# Why won't jpeg save properly to AWS S3 from django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, jpeg, boto3

I'm trying to save a user uploaded file directly to S3 without saving it locally. This project is using Django 1.9 and Boto3.

The relevant code is:

```
p=request.FILES['img'].read()
s3=boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
b = s3.Bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
b.put_object(Key="media/test.jpg", Body=p)
```

This correctly uploads a file called 'test.jpg' to the media folder.

However, if I download 'test.jpg' from Amazon and try to open it in an image viewer, I get the message: "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xf0 0xef)". The jpg file is also only 26kb whereas the original was 116kb.

What is going wrong? I assume I am passing the wrong data as `Body` in the `put_object` method. But what should `p` be instead?

## Update and Solutions

With JordonPhilips's help, I realised that because I had already opened the uploaded image earlier in the view with Pillow, the `request.FILES['img']` socket had already been read.

The solution I went with was to remove the Pillow code, leaving the boto upload as the first access of `request.FILES['img']`.

However, I also figured out a solution if you want to do something to the image first (e.g. in Pillow):

```
from Pillow import Image
import cStringIO as StringIO
import boto3
```

and then in the view function:

```
im = Image.open(request.FILES['img'])
# whatever image analysis here
file2 = StringIO.StringIO()
im.save(file2,"jpeg",quality='keep')
s3 = boto3.resource( 's3', aws_access_key_id=settings. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
b = s3.Bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
b.put_object(Key="media/test.jpg", Body=file2.getvalue())
```

Comment: Could you inspect 'p' to see what it looks like before you send it along?

Comment: you can pass the `file` object directly to `put_object`: `p=request.FILES['img']`

Comment: @JordonPhillips p is of type `str` and len 0 !?

Comment: @ahmed Then I get `ClientError: An error occurred (BadDigest) when calling the PutObject operation: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.`

Comment: @JordonPhillips Thanks for the suggestion, looked at my code in more detail and found the problem. I had already opened the file 10 lines earlier with PIL `im = Image.open(request.FILES['img'])`. If I don't do that, it gets sent to Amazon just fine with `Body=request.FILES['img']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem was that you were trying to read the socket multiple times. You can only read the socket once, so you need to keep reference to important information.